# Javascript replace - remove span element and anything contained within it

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I would like to remove any span element from a string.

So if I have the following string, it should just return `testing`

`<span style="font-family: Lato; font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;">testing`

I was trying to work with this but its not correct
`replace(/<span (.*?)\>/g, '')`

Comment: "_span element_" -> use DOM methods to remove the element, forget string manipulations and RegExp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the span with the content of the span ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lARh15/1)):

```js
var str = '<span style="font-family: Lato; font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400;">testing</span>';

var result = str.replace(/<span[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/span>/g, '$1');

console.log(result);
```